# call stack and immediate windows are missing from display

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Somehow I cannot view any debug-time windows. I select call stack from Debug-> Windows, but it is not shown anywhere. Same with Immediate.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to reset your Visual Studio settings, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx).

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012) discusses several other commandline switches, reportedly for VS2012 but you can always try if they work for VS2010 as well.