# Clicking VS2013 Extensions and Updates Manager causes exception

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I have just installed Visual Studio 2013 and have run into a problem with the Extensions and Updates Manager. When ever I click it I get a "object reference not set to an instance of an object"
See http://screencast.com/t/LKK0TWcz

I've re-installed VS2013 twice...to no avail. Any ideas>>

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio?  if that doesn't work try starting it in safe mode and removing extensions till you find the one that could be the cause

Comment: tried uninstalling, safe mode, standing on my head whilst juggling lemons...still no good.

Comment: that's pretty baffling. Have you tried attachingc a debugger and seeing where the exception is thrown from?  That's the next step I would take.

Comment: Yep...done that..it doesn't break into the debugger for some reason..Turned on break on all errors...just doesn't catch the exception

Comment: did you make sure to disable "just my code"?

Answer (score 3):

Delete all files in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\*.*`.

Comment: You should probably also explain *why* they should delete files. ; )

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Well, It's a hard reset for VS 2013 settings. More details [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25416954/2423859)