# Error in access violation exception was unhandled

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am try to build a WCF class library. So when i try to run the class library it gives me an error of

> An unhandled exception of type System.AccessViolationException
> occurred in WcfSvcHost.exe.
>
> *Message*: Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in System.dll.
>
> *Additional information*: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace, it's easier to solve it that way.

Comment: But it is not showing where is the error where should i use stacktrace ?

Comment: Copy the exception detail

Comment: System.AccessViolationException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in System.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
This is got when i copy exception detail.

Comment: What should i o now buddy ?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294543/programs-randomly-getting-system-accessviolationexception

Comment: It doesnt work for me