# Unable to activiate Windows Store App after failure to install Application Insights

Tags: runtime-error, failed-installation, azure-application-insights

In a project I have tried to install Application Insights, but that failed with an error message and installation of it stopped. I don't remember the exact errormessage, but it was something like  "Namespace/_defaultaApplidation was not found" It was not clear to me what it meant.
'
After that the App (Windows 8.1 StoreApp) would not start anymore. Message (and I can repeat that!) sounds: "Unable to activate Windows Store app". This will not go away.

I have uninstalled Aplication Insights via 'Tools | Extensions ad updates' and removed every trace of Application Insights via Nuget Package Manager. I have rebooted my system between every step.

It has come to a situation where now not a single Store App will start. Even if I start with a new Empty App template, the App comes with the same dreaded error message. I have deleted Bin and Obj folders, built, rebuilt and that ends successfully. But the App won't start....

What do I do now?

Grtz

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem to diagnose. Uninstallation of the ApplicationInsights NuGet package, and removal of the ApplicationInsights.config file should remove all changes. And I'm not sure how the AppInsights packages could be impacting other new projects.

It perhaps sounds like you have a broken Visual Studio environment. Trying to [reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012) or repair your Visual Studio environment would be my recommendation.