# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't load any project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So, I'm kinda new into this VS world. I'm using VS 2012 and it was everything working correctly last time. Now I try to open my projects and none of them actually loads. When I go to the solution explorer I just see the message "Load failed" followed by the message: "The project requires user input. Reload for more information." But when I reload, it pops up a message "The operation could not be completed. There is no support for this interface."

I don't know what it means by "requires user input", i never opened my project with any input, I just click on the project's file and open it...

Anyway, what is going on??

Thanks.

Comment: Look in the "Output" window. There is usually more information there. Depending on how you have VS configured you may need to open the Output window via View => Output.

Comment: Any project at all? Can you create a new blank project? Can you save it, quit, and reopen it?

Comment: There is nothing on the output window. @ta.speot.is

Any project at all! Even a noob project with only one file I had for testing isn't opening. I can't create new ones because it bugs showing the message "package 'visual c++ package' failed to load"

Comment: Sounds like VS is b0rked. You might want to consider resetting your user settings, running devenv.exe in safe mode, running devenv.exe with /resetsettings (kind of heavy handed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012). As a penultimate step you could reinstall VS. And finally, just reformat your computer. Since VS is a complex beast 'n' all, package 42 of 69 is possibly corrupted and good luck fixing that.

Comment: how to run those stuff? I'm completely n00b on VS...

Comment: Probably best to start by just repairing the the installation. Find the Visual Studio 2012 entry in Control Panel -> Programs and Features and double click on it. Then push the "Repair" button.

Comment: I did this and solved the problem, thanks! :)

Comment: See also this SO question which solved my seemingly similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the same message (using VS 2013) opening a project located on a network drive.

I Right clicked the project in Solution Explorer and selected 'Reload Project', a dialog appeared warning me about an untrusted location, I clicked OK and the project loaded successfully.

Comment: This may be ok when the solution contains only one or two projects, but quickly becomes impractical otherwise. Some of our legacy solutions for a large product contain over 200 projects. The answer by @xevser should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @RegEdit fair enough, I don't typically work with solutions involving many projects. Perhaps SO needs a method to have two accepted answers, depending on how many projects you have in your solution ;)

Answer (score 5):

Change the folder name of your project. Then VS asks again if it is trustable. than click YES. after that VS reloads the project

Comment: Worked like a charm for me (VS2013). NOTE instead of the project folder, simplest to rename the solution folder (or move it to a new subfolder). This keeps all the relative project references correct within the solution file.

Answer (score 4):

I had to "repair" Visual Studio Express 2012 on my Windows 10.0 Laptop. You get the repair option if you already have Visual Studio installed.

This fixed my issue which was exactly like above.

Answer (score 4):

I removed the ComponentModelCache folder and restarted Visual Studio 2012.
This solved the issue for me.

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

Comment: This worked for me as well (slightly different path) for VS 2019 solution.  I had several projects within a solution that were not loading.  Deleting the .suo allowed two projects to load, but it wasn't until deleting the "ComponentModelCache" folder that I was able to get the solution to load fully.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well.  I removed the contents of the folder, ComponentModelCache, then I restarted 2012 and the projects loaded without issue.