# Visual studio 2012 crashes when I try to edit .hlsl or .fx files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, hlsl

Visual studio 2012 crashes when I try to edit .hlsl or .fx files, even after I disabled all of my extensions. I also uninstalled Parallel NSight and NShader but the syntax highlighting still shows up for these file types (and seems to be the cause of the problem). Renaming my shader file to have a different extension doesn't cause any problems. Is there a way to manually remove custom syntax highlighting rules?

UPDATE:
Resetting the user data solved my problem.

devenv.exe /ResetUserData -  Removes all user settings and makes you set them again. This will get you the initial prompt for settings again, clear your recent project history, etc.

[How do I truly reset every setting in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have all updates/service packs installed. I don't know if there were any VS 2012 service packs, I use VS 2008 SP1 which is last really stable version known to me.
2. Rename or move temporarily your Visual Studio 2012 folder which is located in "Documents". Visual Studio will create new one.
3. Open VS and see if it helped. If not - problem is elsewhere, so rename/move your Visual Studio 2012 folder back and go to step 3.
4. Backup your Visual Studio settings (Tools -> Import and export settings -> Export...) and then reset them to default (Tools -> Import and export settings -> Reset...).
5. Open VS and try again. If settings reset didn't helped - restore your settings from backup. If it helped - you can import settings by categories and see which one is messed up.
6. Reinstall Visual Studio, something must be messed up in Program Files.