# Visual Studio closes documents after running

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, virtual-machine, parallels

Not sure if this is Parallels related, but I'm running Visual Studio 2013, and one day I my documents started closing after debugging a .NET project.  The expected behavior is that all the files that are open would stay open, but now they all close.  Even after closing the program that's debugging, if I try to open a document to view the code, a new tab does not open because VS thinks the file is still "open."

One fix is to go to **Window > Close All Documents** which closes the files that were open in the background and lets me open the documents while the program is debugging or not debugging.  **Window > Reset Window Layout** wreaks havoc in Parallels, opening tons of other panels like Watch 1, Watch 2, Memory 1, etc.

All I want is to keep files open so I can set breakpoints, or whatever a dev does with a file that's open!  What defaults or setting needs to be reset to keep all the windows open during a run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, after a couple months of "just getting by" with this bug, I finally dedicated some time of my own to fix it.  Ultimately the solution was to delete the user settings.  However, even that brought out some strange issues with my environment.

**CAUTION - This will revert your VS back to first use settings**

Here are the steps:

1) Delete everything in this folder: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio (if you don't see AppData folder, you need to show hidden folders -- In Windows Explorer: Organize\Folder and search options\View and select Show hidden files, folders and drives.)

2) Delete everything in this folder: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

3) Run a command prompt here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE by navigating to that folder then hold Shift+rightclick and select "Open Command Prompt Here"

4) run: "**devenv /ResetUserData**" (following this SO post if needed - [How do I truly reset every setting in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012))

I have a bunch of Git repos set up and all I had to do was open the .sln in the newly reset VS and it automatically added the repo, which was a plus if you thought that would all need to be readded.  Some cases may require a user to delete everything in this folder C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation if you're having issues with scm that's not Git based, and I actually did delete everything in there even though I probably didn't need to in my case.

NOTE:
During this process, I found out that I had three folders C:\Program Files (x86); Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0, Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0. When I ran devenv in the 10.0 folder, it worked, but in 11 and 12, it didn't.  There were a ton of folders and .exe that weren't in the 11 and 12 folders, like devenv.exe, causing a "*'devenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*" I actually had to go into the Control Panel > Add Remove Programs to "Change" my VS install.  I just ran a quick "Modify" by selecting something that wasn't installed and all the folders showed up in the 12.0 folder, so the command would work.

I'm just glad I didn't have to uninstall and reinstall VS.

Comment: Thanks. Really annoying problem, but your solution worked great :)