# Unable to start program in Visual Studio 2013/2012 for debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am getting an error message when trying to debug my project:

Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program
'C:\path\to\project.exe'.
Unrecognized error occoured in the Windows Web Services framework.

This error occurs in all build modes / platform configurations, but not when I launch without debugging (CTRL + F5). Then, it works just fine.

When I tried creating an empty Console Application Project, debugging worked without any problems.

What I tried so far:

- Repair VS 2013
- Reinstall VS 2013
- Install VS 2012 (same error)
- Disable Sophos AntiVirus and Firewall
- Disable Windows Firewall
- Deleting all shadow and temporary files (.suo and stuff)
- Manually reset all settings

I would appreciate any hints...

Comment: You told us which project types work, but nothing about the project that fails to work. What kind of project is it?

Comment: Sorry to not mention that. Actually, both (the clean working console app as well as my project) are C# console app projects. So no difference there.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer in another question (see [this stackoverflow.com question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012)).

Using the command prompt, I ran

```
devenv.exe /ResetAddin 
devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs 
devenv.exe /ResetUserData
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

After full reinstall, all setings seemed to be cleared, but somehow this was not the case.