# Visual Studio 2015 crashes with KernelBase error in EventLogs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 RTM crashes when opening some solutions consistently.

In the Event Log Viewer it shows application "Fault Module KernelBase.DLL"

I have tried resetting settings as mentioned on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012).

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by doing a ResetUserData and Repair from Program and Features in Control Panel.

1. Do a `.\devenv /ResetUserData` (It will reset everything including customizations and all)
2. Goto Control Panel > Program and Features and repair Visual Studio 2015.
3. Restart your computer.