# VS 2010: value does not fall within the expected range on search

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

ever since I restarted my computer, when I open ANY of the solution using Visual studio 2010 to search CTRL + COMMA, I got the error: value does not fall within the expected range. I have no clue why this suddenly happen, when I restarted my computer, it performed a disk check or something.

Comment: Possibly similar to a problem with VS2008 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8fe36d87-c432-47e7-9303-9b4e8707ae9e/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-design-view-settings-file-error?forum=winformsdesigner   Try deleting the .user or .suo files

Comment: this is not working for me, do you have other suggestion?

Comment: Try reset your visual studio settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012