# Team explorer 2015 View Builds generate Malformed Artifact URI error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild, team-explorer, tfs-power-tools

I am having an issue with Team explorer in visual studio 2015 Update 1 RC.
The server is TFS 2013.

When I want to View Builds of a specific build, I have this error message

> Malformed Artifact URI: [Build name]
>
> Parameter name: uri

[image]

This is working using Visual studio 2013 on the same machine, and working with visual studio 2015 on other machine. So this is not a problem with the server.
Only 2 machines have the issue, and both have the extension TFS power tools 2015 installed.

I tried:

- Remove the extension
- Clear Team foundation cache
- Repair visual studio
- Hard reset all settings

Didn't resolve the issue.

"Edit build definition" and "Queue new build" are working.

Any ideas other than uninstall and reinstall visual studio?

Thanks

Edit:
- Creating a New build definition in VS2015 is working, but trying to open it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in VS2015 update1. You need to download and install it: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: Great news. This is working with the update. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue in my Visual Studio 2015 just after the Update1 RC is installed.

Here is my Visual Studio version:
[image]

I have reported this issue. You can also submit one feedback on the [Microsoft Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/LoadSubmitFeedbackForm).

Now, you need to open TFS web access directly to view one build. Or you need to uninstall Update1 RC.

Comment: Thanks. I do have Update 1 RC installed on both machine having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning cache folder on your client machine: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`. And clean the cache on your TFS AT machine: `C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache`

Then, on your client machine, resetting settings and add-in settings with [devenv /ResetSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx) and [devenv /ResetSkipPkgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276.aspx), try rebuilding all templates with [devenv /setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, none of these fixed the issue.

Comment: Even completely resetting the settings does't work. Following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203820/how-do-i-truly-reset-every-setting-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: What's the TFS version are you using? Do you check a vNext build or a XAML build? Can you reproduce this issue on a new build with the same VS? Please share the entire error log here.

Comment: This is Xaml build. Server TFS 2013. Creating new Build in the same VS can't be opened. How can I get the logs details of error occuring in the Team explorer? Thank you for your help