# Selected visual studio item '...' failed to install. Check the %TEMP% directory for VS install logs

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm facing with this issue, when trying to install updates using 'Extensions and Updates' dialog:

[image]

I've checked `%TEMP%` (`%MyUserName%\AppData\Local\Temp`), but at first look there's nothing related to VS install logs. A couple of days ago everything was working fine, and I have no idea, how to fix it.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416954/580053) answer and tried to reset VS settings using `/ResetUserData` and `/ResetSettings` switches.

Does anybody have any ideas? At least, where mentioned log file could be located?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: I've installed Update 2 and this have solved the problem.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issues with Update 3 and 'Tools for Universal Windows Apps (1.4.1) and Windows SDK (10.0.14393)' extension.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by downloading and running the VS installer "vs_community_ENU.exe" from [download-visual-studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx).

The installer didn't recognize my current VS 2015 installation (even though my VS worked). It installed all over again, or at least the missing packages or something.

The important thing was that it kept all the extensions and configurations. Just running the installer solved the issue.

Hope this helps somebody.

**Update**

The VS 2015 installer is now a little harder to find. Please find it here: [my.visualstudio.com](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015)

> My.VisualStudio.com requires a free Dev Essentials subscription, or a
>   Visual Studio Subscription.

Reference: [Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 Release Notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs)

Comment: can't find the file at the end of the link you provided. Searched the site. Ken...

Comment: @KenCarter hmmm, apparently things have changed. I'll update my answer. It's a little harder to find the VS 2015 installer now

Comment: I didn't have time to come back and let you know but I did locate it on a sub page from the link you'd provided but oddly enough the file name isn't searchable on the site. Kinda odd but anyhow... if you look for the community name in the title you'll find it easy enough.